# Reading button state of self holding is high all the time

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, button

I have a self-holding circuit for a push button that is used as the power button for a 7.4 V supply. The button state should be read by a `PI4IOE5V9539` port expander.

Unfortunately, the port expander is reading `1` as the state of the `ON_OFF` signal most of the time. Sometimes the state goes back to `0`. I measure a voltage of 0.7 V when the push button is released at the point of the `ON_OFF` signal.

[image]

My suggestion is that the voltage comes from the diode of `Q207` and that voltage is high enough to force a `1` state on the port expander.

How can I fix this issue? My first idea is to place a pull-down next to the diode. Is this a good way to do it or is there a better solution?

Comment: What is the supply voltage of the IO expander, and how is it configured? Will it also have it's supply turned off when Q207 is off? How do you know it's really 0.7V, what if it is higher, but because the impedances are so high that using a multimeter loads the ON_OFF line down to 0.7V - which should be logic 0.

Comment: The supply voltage for the port expander is 3.3 V and it is powered from `Q207`. `Q207` acts as the main power switch for the complete design. I´m not 100% sure if the voltage is 0.7 V. I have measured the voltage with a multimeter and the multimeter displays that value. I also have connected a pull-down parallel to `D201` and it seems that the problem is gone. After that change, I can read out the button without any issues.

Comment: I see no proper path for ON_OFF to be pulled down. I would add a 1M resistor in parallel with D201 to fix that.